# Double click text selection - Backspace hotkey problem

Tags: keyboard, mouse

last night i had to reinstall my os because of deleteing an important parts of os

and after reinstall everythings was ok

but now i have 2 problems:

1 - before, when i clicke 2 time (double click) on texts, i could select texts as i need,  if you dont understand my mean tell me to explain it more

2 - i have problem in keyboard hotkeys hold, for example: when you hold backspace, all texts delete automatically in a few seconds. or when you wanna type "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", just need hold "A" hotkey in your keyboard, but seems like keys holding is disable in my os, becuase when i hold every hotkeys, they act one time and the examples i told dont work in my os

My os: ubuntu 20.04 desktop

thanks ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Keys holding and repeated keys: Setting => Universal Access => Typing => Repeat Keys (Be sure it ticked)

Mouse double click: Setting => Universal Access => Pointing & Clicking => Mouse Keys (Be sure it ticked)

You can absolutly set Delay and Speed for "repeat keys" option by clicking on it's title